# xmodmap configuration to emulate Mac special key layout?

Tags: macintosh, xmodmap

On my Mac, I frequently type curly quotes manually. For example, a left curly double quote is Option-[. I would like to do the same on my Linux box. I run vanilla X11 (FVWM) with no GNOME, KDE, etc.

Is there an xmodmap file out there that maps the curly quotes, and ideally all the rest of the Option and Shift-Option characters, to the same key combinations as Macs use?

Comment: Does it have to be the same keys? It's possible to produce a large array of characters with the compose key. For example I can write ” with `<Compose><'><'>`.